# optional/mandatory participation in E/R model

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I am kinda confused about the two notations in the E/R model.
The left picture represent that STAFF MUST participate in TUTOR relationship, but STUDENT NEED NOT participate in TUTOR relationship. My understanding is that it means that every staff in STAFF entity set should be participating TUTOR relationship but some students in STUDENT entity set might not participate, which means some student could have NULL tutor staff in it's table, but staff who participate in TUTOR relationship need to have tutored-student. Does this then become the same idea as the right graph? That staff could not have zero student, but student could have no tutor?

Are they the same in general? Or do they actually have different meaning? Thank you! (I have searched for some similar questions but still didn't get what I want to know)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the notation on the right before, but it seems intuitive to interpret it in the same way. One difference is that the notation on the left uses the look-here convention for participation constraints (while using the look-across convention for cardinality indicators) whereas the notation on the right uses the look-across convention for both features.